# How can I search/replace and retain a part that varies between the results?

Tags: substitute

What I'm trying to do is reformat some ugly JSON, replacing a pile of lines that are formatted:

```
[whitespace][number],\n
```

for example:

```
         5,
```

I have thousands of those lines, but don't know how to search and replace while retaining that number which differs with each line.  Would someone be able to help me out?

The end result I want is to group all sets of those lines on to a single line, like "    8, 6, 0, 6" etc.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Welcome indeed! Can you clarify one thing for me? Are you saying you have blocks of consecutive lines following this pattern, and you want to condense each block of lines into a single line?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: Yes, that's correct; thousands of lines of [spaces][number][comma].  I actually managed to resolve this with a bunch of search/replaces as the lines I want were unique in being indented 12 characters.  I just replaced occurrences of \n[12 spaces] with a single space.  It would nonetheless be very nice to know if there's a "proper" way to do that.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh - I think I should have clarified that.  Yes, these are groups of lines separated by other distinct lines (additional data).  The sequences of numbers are in individual groups of as much as 100-ish lines.

Comment: @JacobEwing given that additional constraint, your way is probably easier to come up with interactively. My answer took a bit of thinking, but should work more generically in case this comes up again (plus you can tweak the pattern).

Comment: @JacobEwing You might want to [edit] the question to clarify you have non-matching lines interspersed with the "number" lines. Right now that information is only in the comments here and it's non-obvious from the current phrasing of the question... Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was harder than I thought it was going to be. Naïvely, I expected something like

```
global/^\s*\d\+,/join
```

to work, but it turns out this global applies one `:join` at a time to each matching line, so it doesn't work. (P.S. `:join` is the Ex command that joins two lines; its normal-mode equivalent is `J`.)

Here's a test case:

```
a
1,
b
c
    5,
        6,
    7,
    d
    e
    f
8,
    9,
  10,
```

If you run the command I tried, you get

```
a
1, b
c
    5, 6,
    7, d
    e
    f
8, 9,
  10,
```

---

Instead, we need to be smarter: we need to find the "blocks" of numbers and then `:join` them all at once. I had *hoped* to be able to do this with `:global` (pseudocode):

```
global /pattern for digit-lines/,/pattern for non-digit lines/-1 join
```

but I couldn't quite make a negative patterns work (and I'm now disappointed that vim doesn't have a "negation" operator that applies to a pattern to produce its exact negative—that, or I misunderstood `\@!` &co., and negative matching is just *hard*).

So I came up with the following solution (which should be quite fast, but will take time proportional to the length of the file):

```
function! GroupNums() abort
  const line_pat = '^\s*\d\+,$'
  1
  while search(line_pat, 'W')
    let first_line = line('.')
    +
    while getline('.') =~# line_pat && line('.') != line('$')
      +
    endwhile
    " now current line matches and is the last line, or doesn't match (and the
    " end of the block is one above)
    let last_line = getline('.') =~# line_pat ? line('$') : line('.') - 1
    execute first_line ',' last_line 'join'
  endwhile
endfunction
```

Create this function (you can type it interactively if you want, but you can also paste it into `/tmp/code.vim` and do `:source /tmp/code.vim` if you want), then switch to the buffer to fix and run `:call GroupNums()`.

With the test-case, I get

```
a
1,
b
c
    5, 6, 7,
    d
    e
    f
8, 9, 10,
```

---

For the curious, the algorithm follows at a high level. Starting from the top of the file (`1`), we find the start of a block (`search(line_pat, 'W')`). We never wrap around, so we only process each block once. We record the start of the block (`line('$')`). Then, we move down one line at a time (`+`) scanning until we reach the end of the file or the end of the block (the inner while's condition: `getline('.') =~# line_pat && line('.') != line('$')`). The loop invariant guarantees that one or both of the following are true:

1. We are at the end of the file;
2. The current line does not match the pattern.

If the current line matches the pattern, then we must be at the end of the file, so we can use that for the end of the block (`line('$')`). Otherwise, we can use whatever the line before the current line is, because it matched and now the current line does not (`line('.')-1`). (Notice that it does not matter if we are the end of the file *and* the current line does not match; the second case covers this adequately.)

Having reached the end of the block, we do a `:<start>,<end> join` to group the lines together, and search for the next block. Of course, if we are already at the end, this search will fail because we do not wrap and because the pattern does not match already-joined lines, which the last line may be).

Comment: If your vim does not have `const`, you can use `let` instead...

Comment: This one works quite well for me, and it's fairly simple...: `:%s/\(\d\+\),\n\s*/\1,`

Comment: @filbranden That's will join the last line with a number, even if there's no number in the next one, won't it? Maybe `:%s/\(\d\+\),\n\s*\ze\d,/\1,` (not tested). (Tested, looks like I'm more right than Fil -- champagne).

Comment: Good job @Biggybi!  Yeah I guess using `\n` on a regex will be easier than using `:join` in a `:global`...

Comment: @filbranden Indeed! I don't mean to command you, but should maybe make it an answer as well.

Comment: @Biggybi Go for it if you like! Really, please do.

Comment: @filbranden it'll be an honor!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a relatively simple regular expression with `:substitute`:

```
:%s/\(\d\+,\)\n\s*\ze\d\+,/\1
```

- `:%s` start a substitution on the whole file
- `\(\d\+\),\n\s*` is the pattern to be replaced

  - `\(\d\+,\)` create a group (`()`) (to use later) of any number (`\+`) of numbers (`\d`) followed by `,`
  - `,\n\s*` match a `,` followed by a new line (`\n`), `space` (`\s`), anything until... (`*`)
- `\ze` stop matching here: do not replace the following, but check if it's here

  - `\d\+,` ...numbers followed by a coma (to make sure we join only lines with numbers)
- `\1` replace the matching pattern with the group created earlier (that is, the x numbers followed by `,` from `\(\d\+,\)`)

Courtesy to [filbranden](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/25541/how-can-i-search-replace-and-retain-a-part-that-varies-between-the-results/25543?noredirect=1#comment44998_25543)

Comment: Well done, you two; glad to see there was a simple solution. I struggled hard with `global` before writing the loops bc I didn't thing `substitute` could do it! I *think* this works over `global` because of the way `:%s` is processed, but I want to do some digging. Nit: you could include the comma in the capture and remove it in the replace.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble indeed, capturing the comma is cleaner. Although I do not understand what you mean by  `/I think.*processed`, I wish you luck in your research :P

Comment: @D.BenKnoble One more is that this could potentially use `\zs`, so you actually only *remove* newline and space... `%s/\d,\zs\n\s*\ze\d\+,//`. I also don't know whether matching whitespace before the initial `\d\+` will work. It would be nice to do so to ensure we're only matching cases that consist entirely of numbers, but it might break the solution since the `\s` would be matched on both lines... Really quite tricky and interesting problem!

Comment: @filbranden Both our substitute command and this one with `\zs` match numbers only, or I'm not sure what you mean. Btw, even nicer implementation with that `\zs`! I'm almost certain you can't improve it further.